# How do I block a package's dependencies from explicit apt-get remove?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I need to use

```
sudo apt-get -y --purge remove $manypackages
```

where `$manypackages` includes dependencies of a package that I don't want removed.

Is it possible to prevent `apt-get` from removing those dependencies instead of me having to determine them and remove them from the `$manypackages` list beforehand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to prevent explicitly removing packages, which is what the command you want to issue will do. A workaround is to mark the packages as auto, then let apt autoremove the ones that are no longer needed.

```
sudo apt-mark auto $many_packages
sudo apt-mark manual $keep_packages
sudo apt autoremove
```